# Pandas: Filter DataFrameGroupBy (df.groupby) based on group aggregates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
df
| a  | b |
|----|---|
| 10 | 1 |
| 10 | 5 |
| 11 | 1 |
```

straight grouping it using

```
grouped = df.groupby('a')
```

Lets get only groups where

```
selector = grouped.b.max() - grouped.b.min() >= 3
```

yields

```
df
| a  |       |
|----|-------|
| 10 | True  |
| 11 | False |
```

My questions is, what is the **equivalent** for `df = df.loc[<filter condition>]` when working with `DataFrameGroupBy` elements?

[`grouped.filter(..)` returns a `DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html).

Is there a way to preserve the groups, while filtering based on `.aggreate()` functions? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @yatu, no, it did not answer the question. Your solution is not containing any benefit from my written code. The question was *not* how to archive the `Series` of `True` or `False` for the filter criteria - That worked fine using `grouped.b.max() - grouped.b.min() >= 3`. The original question was, how I *apply* these `True|False` selector to the `DataFrameGroupBy` to only keep those groups, which are `True`. In other words: I want to filter out those groups, which are `False` based on the `selector`.

Comment: How about just [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with the result then?

Comment: Exactly :) I am searching for a solution to only keep those groups which are `True`. It can be done easily using `df.loc` on DataFrames, but I do not see a function for `DataFrameGroupBy`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.ptp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html) (peak-to-peak)

```
df.groupby('a').b.agg(np.ptp) > 3
```

---

```
a
10     True
11    False
Name: b, dtype: bool
```

Comment: I was not aware of `np.ptp` - Thanks! Nevertheless, sadly, this is just an alternative version of `grouped.b.max() - grouped.b.min() >= 3`. This was not the question - I commented on the question above to make it more clear.

Comment: Posted a solution based on two `groupby`, wondering if there is no direct filtering possibility on `DataFrameGroupBy`

Comment: @gies0r hmm interesting. Could you explain further?

Comment: Added additional comments to the answer + fixed a quick error. Hopefully it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

For the `df.loc[]` equivalent question, you can just do:

```py
df=df.set_index('a')\
    .loc[df.groupby('a').b.agg(np.ptp).gt(3)]\
    .reset_index()
```

Alternatively (inner join solution):

```py
selector=df.groupby('a').b.agg(np.ptp).gt(3)
selector=selector.loc[selector]
df=df.merge(selector, on='a', suffixes=["", "_dropme"])
df=df.loc[:, filter(lambda col: "_dropme" not in col, df.columns)]
```

Outputs:

```py
    a  b
0  10  1
1  10  5
```

PS +1 @rafaelc - for the `.ptp` thing

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I did not came around a direct solution.. So I worked around it like this using 2 `groupby`:

```
# Build True/False Series for filter criteria
selector = df.groupby('a').b.agg(np.ptp) > 3

# Only select those 'a' which have True in filter criteria
selector = selector.loc[selector == True]

# Re-Create groups of 'a' with the filter criteria in place
# Only those groups for 'a' will be created, where the MAX-MIN of 'b' are > 3.
grouped = df.loc[df['a'].isin(selector.index)].groupby('a')
```

Comment: `groupby('a').isin` doesn't exist. I'm not sure what you want your final result to be? (this code doesn't run)

Comment: @rafaelc That was a quick error - I fixed it in my code with different variable names and abstracted it to this example. Fixed it know :)